# Trying to make a horizontal table puts the table off the page, how should it be used?

Tags: tables, rotating

I tried landscape, sideways, sidewaystable but they place my table (without turning) outside of the page (see bottom for picture). I'm using sharelatex to make my pdfs, could be a problem with that. Otherwise, how do I get my table to go horizontal?

### Sample table

```
\documentclass[dvips,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\footnotesize{}
\caption{Caption. }
\tabcolsep=0.12cm
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}
\hline
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{B} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{C} \\
\cmidrule(r{10pt}){2-5} \cmidrule(l{6pt}r{10pt}){6-9} \cmidrule(l{6pt}){10-13}
Z & Y & X & Q. & W & E & S & T & L & M & S & V & R \\
\hline
1       &       35165   &       48.7\%  &       35165   &       3.5\%   &       6756    &       35.3\%  &
    6756    &       9.0\%   &       0       &       0.0\%   &       0       &       0.0     \\
2       &       11780   &       16.3\%  &       23560   &       2.3\%   &       5086    &       26.6\%  &
    10172   &       13.6\%  &       779     &       5.8\%   &       1558    &       0.2     \\
3-5     &       9669    &       13.4\%  &       36003   &       3.6\%   &       4143    &       21.7\%  &
    15331   &       20.5\%  &       1961    &       14.7\%  &       7619    &       0.9     \\
6-10    &       5078    &       7.0\%   &       38405   &       3.8\%   &       1784    &       9.3\%   &
    13190   &       17.6\%  &       2127    &       15.9\%  &       16553   &       1.9     \\
11-15   &       2285    &       3.2\%   &       29192   &       2.9\%   &       603     &       3.2\%   &
    7634    &       10.2\%  &       1329    &       9.9\%   &       17109   &       2.0     \\
16-25   &       2543    &       3.5\%   &       51499   &       5.1\%   &       459     &       2.4\%   &
    8957    &       12.0\%  &       1834    &       13.7\%  &       37559   &       4.4     \\
26-50   &       2287    &       3.2\%   &       83445   &       8.3\%   &       218     &       1.1\%   &
    7499    &       10.0\%  &       1983    &       14.8\%  &       72967   &       8.5     \\
51-100  &       1795    &       2.5\%   &       126972  &       12.6\%  &       62      &       0.3\%   &
    4229    &       5.6\%   &       1704    &       12.8\%  &       120788  &       14.1    \\
101-500 &       1460    &       2.0\%   &       277190  &       27.6\%  &       8       &       0.0\%   &
    1184    &       1.6\%   &       1449    &       10.8\%  &       275645  &       32.3    \\
500+    &       195     &       0.3\%   &       304695  &       30.3\%  &       0       &       0.0\%   &
    0       &       0.0\%   &       195     &       1.5\%   &       304695  &       35.7    \\
Total   &       72257   &       ~       &       1006126 &       ~       &       19119   &       ~    &  7
4952    &       ~       &       13361   &       ~       &       854493  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: table]

Comment: i see two problems here: instead of `rotation`, i believe the package name is `rotating`.  and if you remove `dvips` from the options to the document class and process the file with pdflatex, the table is indeed set rotated and within the page boundaries.  but since you are creating your pdf file in a different manner, i'm not sure how to advise you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are viewing the `dvi` output. View the `ps` or `pdf` output instead. `dvi` viewers cannot show rotations. If you are already using `pdflatex` then delete the `dvips` option for the document class.

Answer (score 0):

1. The package name is `rotating`, not `rotation`, thus it should be `\usepackage{rotating}`
2. Either remove the `dvips` from the class options to compile the document with `pdflatex`, or use `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`.